# What are the Steps to start appium servers for multiple devices through command prompt

Tags: appium

I have written one script which ran on single device.
Now, I want to run the same script on multiple devices, by googling i come to know that we can do by creating multiple instances of appium server.

How to create multiple instances of appium server through command line?

Can anyone provide steps to start with?

Please suggest.

BR,
Sagar Varpe

Comment: Hi, welcome. This type of question has already been asked here, which is probably why your question got a down-vote. Please try to show what research you have already done to answer your own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open multiple terminals and change the port and bootstrap port on each terminal. Like this:

```
Terminal 1 - appium -p 4722 -bp 5422
Terminal 2 - appium -p 4723 -bp 5423
Terminal 3 - appium -p 4724 -bp 5424
```

and so on.

Comment: Hi, I used appium -p 4722 -bp 5422 and appium UI got launched. But when i checked the general settings, it shows port number as 4723 as we have provided 4722.
Please help.

Comment: please post a new question with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

install appium using npm in global location.

```
npm install -g appium
```

Then in two three terminal windows, type

```
appium -p <port1> -U <device name> -bp <bpPort1>
appium -p <port2> -U <device name> -bp <bpPort2>
```

To get the device name , type adb devices. Appium port - port1, port2 etc should be different and have difference of atleast 10. Same goes to bootstrap port bpPort1, bpPort2 in above command. Device name is the different device that you want to connect to. Appium requires one server per one device.

If you are using selendriod then you have to add selendriod port as well(--selendriod-port

If you require to run the nodejs server that appium GUI client starts on clicking  start button, then you have to start just the node server from command line like as below

```
node . -p <port1> -U <device name> -bp <bpPort1>
```

Comment: By using this i can launch the appium but could not get it to start.
Can anybody tell the command to start the node.

Comment: not sure what you are trying. running appium on command line would run appium server. Are you trying to run appium GUI?Appium when installed as exe would come with a Gui , and appium nodejs code as well. What is error you getting?

Comment: By using "appium -p <port1> -U <device name> -bp <bpPort1>"
I can launch the GUI of appium which we can launch by double clicking on its icon also. But I want to run the appium as like we click on Play button of GUI which is at top left of GUI.

Comment: in the directory where you have installed appium GUI client open commandline , try "node . -p <port1> -U <device name> -bp <bpPort1>". What you trying to launch is appium gui client. If you want the server to be run, then you have to use node. This command above will launch the appium node server in command line