# What is the relation between node js and appium? How to run to multiple instances of appium servers on two different ports?

Tags: android, node.js, appium

What is the relation between node js and appium?

How to run to multiple instances of appium servers on two different ports?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Steps to start appium servers for multiple devices through command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827751/what-are-the-steps-to-start-appium-servers-for-multiple-devices-through-command)

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [What are the Steps to start appium servers for multiple devices through command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827751/what-are-the-steps-to-start-appium-servers-for-multiple-devices-through-command)
and also refer below the shared links to get some information.

What is the relation between node js and appium?
Ref this:
http://appium.io/introduction.html
How to run to multiple instances of appium servers on two different ports?
Ref this:
https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/speeding-test-execution-appium